# python how to update scrapy to 0.22

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am working with python 2.7 with scrapy 0.20

I would like to try scrapy 0.22, how to do that please?

I tried

`pip scrapy update`

but I got error message

I followed this question 
stackoverflow.com/questions/21258961/how-do-i-update-scrapy-from-the-terminal

and I used `pip install --upgrade scrapy`

but when I run `scrapy verion` on cmd, I got 0.20

I am using windows 7

could u help please

#### Edit

a user suggest to update the pip and I got this excpetion when updating the pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", l
ine 134, in main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.p
y", line 241, in run
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1306
, in install
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 537,
 in commit_uninstall
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1663
, in commit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 42,
 in rmtree
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 244, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 244, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 249, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 61,
 in rmtree_errorhandler
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp
\\pip-xw1mij-uninstall\\python27\\scripts\\pip.exe'

Storing complete log in C:\Users\User\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to upgraded pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then upgrade scrapy:

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
```

or...

You may need to upgraded pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then remove scrapy:

```
pip uninstall scrapy
```

Then reinstall scrapy:

```
pip install scrapy
```

Comment: please check my edit, i got an exception and i posted it

Comment: Try the `Run as Administrator` option to run the program and try the upgrade again.

Comment: ^ this. You may have to run CMD as admin.