# scrapy showing old version after pip install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I tried installing/upgrading scrapy and it says it has installed verison 0.24. Yet, when i try using it, it does not recognize the newer versions commands like crawl etc. i.e. it is still stuck at the older version. What should be done?

```
Collecting scrapy from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.24.5-py2-none-any.whl#md5=f4da05854ea6ea0692b665c1758f0dfe
  Downloading Scrapy-0.24.5-py2-none-any.whl (444kB)
    100% |################################| 446kB 343kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyOpenSSL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: w3lib>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: cryptography>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: cffi>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cffi>=0.8->cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Installing collected packages: scrapy
  Found existing installation: Scrapy 0.12.0.2546
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scrapy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Can't uninstall 'Scrapy'. No files were found to uninstall.

    Successfully installed scrapy-0.24.5

scrapy --version

Scrapy 0.12.0.2546 - no active project
```

Comment: already checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089073/python-how-to-update-scrapy-to-0-22

Comment: are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Hi @Ady,

Were you able to resolve the problem?